# Jquery Drag interface like on http://filippasmedhagensund.com/

Tags: jquery, navigation, drag, user-experience

we are in the process of building a websites with the characteristics of this:
http://filippasmedhagensund.com/

We would like to have 100% width and 100% height responsive "screens" and a drag/slide navigation.

Anybody can point us in the right direction to develop this using JQuery?
Any ready-made solutions?

Thanks.